# Помогите переписать LINQ Query на Scala

Tags: scala

Оригинальный Query:

```
var rez = planes
    .Where(b => (b.FlDate >= dateFrom) && (b.FlDate <= dateTo))
    .GroupBy(i => i.Destination)
    .Select(g => new { Destination = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
    .ToList();
```

Scala-код:

```
var rez = planes
  .filter( _.FlDate.getMillis >= dateFrom.getMillis)
  .filter(_.FlDate.getMillis <= dateTo.getMillis)
  .groupBy(_.Destination)
  .flatMap( new { Destination:String = _.Key, Count = _.Count() })
```

Проблема именно в строке

```
.flatMap( new { Destination:String = _.Key, Count = _.Count() })
```

Никак не могу её побороть.

То есть у меня должен выйти в конце любой список анонимных объектов с двумя параметрами: `Count` и `Destination`.

Comment: Наверное, `a.Key` и `a.Count()`?

Comment: не, точно не. Эта строка в любом случае неправильная. Вот понять бы как правильно будет)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ: Правильными кверями будут:

Если не нужно называть проперти обьекта:

```
val rez: Map[String, Int] = planes
      .filter(logRow => logRow.FlDate.isAfter(dateFrom) && logRow.FlDate.isBefore(dateTo))
      .groupBy(_.Destination)
      .map { case (location, logRows) => (location, logRows.length) }
```

или если нужно называть проперти обьекта:

```
val rez = planes
      .filter(logRow => logRow.FlDate.isAfter(dateFrom) && logRow.FlDate.isBefore(dateTo))
      .groupBy(_.Destination)
      .map {
        case (location, logRows) => new {
          val destination = location;
          val count = logRows.length
        }
      }
```